# Making File Path as a Variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to Python and I am trying to get a bit of code to concatenate text files into one!

I have the following code:

```
Checkpoint = open("/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Checkpoint.txt", "r")
eightbyeight = open("/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_8x8.txt", "r")
AmazonAWS = open("/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_AmazonAWS.txt", "r")
Common_Tech_Terms = open("/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Common_Tech_Terms.txt", "r")

import sys

filenames = ['Common_Tech_Terms', 'eightbyeight', 'AmazonAWS', 'Checkpoint']
with open('output_file2.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/Combining Files", line 60, in <module>
    with open(fname) as infile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Common_Tech_Terms'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/Combining Files"]
[dir: /Users/owenmurray/Desktop]
```

Anyone have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Check the error: `No such file or directory: 'Common_Tech_Terms'`

Comment: You might want to edit your heading as well to attract the correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do:

```
Checkpoint = open("/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Checkpoint.txt", "r")
```

Then you will need to manually close the file as well:

```
Checkpoint.close()
```

---

Instead simply do:

```
# Updated. Removed "open(, 'r')"
Checkpoint = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Checkpoint.txt"
eightbyeight = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_8x8.txt"
AmazonAWS = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_AmazonAWS.txt"
Common_Tech_Terms = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Common_Tech_Terms.txt"

import sys

# Removed "". We need variable Common_Tech_Terms, not string "Common_Tech_Terms".
filenames = [Common_Tech_Terms, eightbyeight, AmazonAWS, Checkpoint]
with open('output_file2.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the benefit of using a context manager, call `open` when you need a file content:

```
Checkpoint = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Checkpoint.txt"
eightbyeight = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_8x8.txt"
AmazonAWS = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_AmazonAWS.txt"
Common_Tech_Terms = "/Users/owenmurray/Desktop/vocab/Custom_Vocab_Split_by_Brand_Common_Tech_Terms.txt"

filenames = [Common_Tech_Terms, eightbyeight, AmazonAWS, Checkpoint]
with open('output_file2.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname, "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line + "\n")
```